# R split string by tab or nonprinting character

Tags: r, split

I have one line of string, first delimited by tab and  then inside each column sub columns are delimited by ^A. 
Anyone knows how to do that in R.

I even failed split the line by 'tab' on the first step, my code is below and I am using Rscript to read from stdin:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

input = file('stdin', 'r')

while(length(row<-readLines(input, n=1))>0){
    fields = strsplit(row, '\t')
    key = fields[1]
    value = fields[2]
    write(length(fields), stdout())
}
```

Then I run my code:

```
$ cat input | ./reducer.R 
1
1
1
```

and my input looks like this which is tab delimited:

```
1        2
3        4
5        6
```

I just cannot understand why my split statement doesnt' work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell without your input, but you probably want:

```
key = fields[[1]][[1]]
value = fields[[1]][[2]]
```

If the above works, chances are so will the following:

```
fields = strsplit(row, '\t') [[1]]
key = fields[1]
value = fields[2]
```

`strsplit` returns a list (great for vectorized operations, but a `gotcha` when not expecting a list output)

Comment: This works for me, but totally unexpected complex just for a split.. of course, comparing with Python

Comment: @B.Mr.W., please see the edit.   `Python` syntax is certainly easier when splitting a single string.  However, in `R`, you don't even need your while loop.  You can accomplish that entire code in two lines. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop or `strsplit()` at all:

```
f <- read.delim(stdin(), sep="\t", header=FALSE)
names(f) <- c("key", "value")
```

`f` is now a data frame that contains two columns, your key and value.

If you want to write it somewhere, use `write.table`:

```
write.table(f, stdout(), sep="\t", row.names=FALSE)
```